# how to get data by using intent filter in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to generate url to particular activity because I wanted to share this particular url through my app and when we click on that url my activity should be opened ...I tried many ways but did not get the result.I added intent filter to the activity in my manifest file as

```
<activity
            android:name="com.bodaty.samyata.samyata4.customer_service.Contacts"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />-->
            <action android:name ="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name ="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name ="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="www.samyata.com"
                />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In oncreate of my activity I added like this

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
Uri data = intent.getData();
Log.e("dataaa", String.valueOf(data));
```

I wanted to generate url to open particular product detail page but I am unable to generate url ...I am trying to print data but data is always null why can anyone help me please

```
08-02 05:48:18.049 13864-13864/com.bodaty.samyata.samyata4 E/dataaa: null
08-02 05:48:40.488 13864-13864/com.bodaty.samyata.samyata4 E/dataaa: null
```

Comment: Is this when you click on link ?

Comment: Show code starting your activity to open URL.

Comment: I actually thought intent filter creates a link specified with data and I wanted to generate dynamic links by adding path but data is null in oncreate

Comment: I am new to this please help me to find a way I wanted to share link through WhatsApp  and when I click on whats app my activity should be opened so I am trying to generate link to my activity how should I generate link ....I saw many posts , every post is showing me code as above but data is always null can anyone say me procedure to do this

Comment: @sontruongit I wanted to generate link to my activity but I am unable to create

Comment: What URL would you like to open?

Comment: When you click on URL, your activity open but no data, is that correct?

Comment: I have many products in my app and every product details page would specify all the details of that product so I wanted to generate a link to this activity and share through WhatsApp and when I click on that link I wanted to open my activity so in order to do this what should I do

Comment: what do you want to see happen when you call `Log.e("dataaa", String.valueOf(data));` ?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
Uri uri = (Uri)bundle.get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
```

more information for https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive

Answer (score -2):

**If your application handles receiving text content, a single image of any type, or multiple images of any type, your manifest would look like:**

```
<activity android:name=".ui.MyActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

[Please refer , How to handle the incoming content](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive)